# Hosting a winforms user control in asp.net web page

Tags: c#, .net, activex

I am trying to host an existing win-forms usercontrol in a webpage. I am following the steps as sugested in the link https://web.archive.org/web/20210619191631/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx.

To summarize inline -

the sample creates a windows control library project and uses the object tag to host the control in a web page

```
<OBJECT id="MyWinControl1" height="200" width="200" classid="http:WinControls.dll#WinControls.WinTreeview" VIEWASTEXT>
    <PARAM NAME="Title" VALUE="My Title">
</OBJECT>
```

i tried the sample they had provided inline and it worked fine. Tried creating my own controls and as long as i used simple controls (check box, radio button etc) it seemed to work fine. But once i started using more complex controls like a report viewer(the actual control i am trying to host also has the same issue) the control stopped rendering. I see a empty box with a image at the top left control.

I am not sure what the problem is and how i can debug this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used wpf xbap, its basically a wpf browser application with a windows application host control.
you can then publish your application with a certificate that then needs to be imported into your browser and your good to go.

Check this [link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/maxim/archive/2008/03/05/wpf-xbap-as-full-trust-application.aspx) for more info